# Matlab will only plot points on my graph but wont connect them with any of the line types

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to make it plot this function which should be a straight line but it is only plotting points. I'm very new to Matlab and we haven't learned how to do this in class yet so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Code:

```
x = linspace(-30,30,31);  
y = sin(x)/x;  
plot(x,y,'-ro');  
axis([-30 30 -1 1])  
xlabel('x')  
ylabel('y')  
title('Philips Graph')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have only one point the the `y` matrix.

Try

```
y=sin(x)./x
```

This will make the division of every point [(rdivide)](http://se.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html), not a matrix operation [(mrdivide)](http://se.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html).

For your example, you also have the problem of the zero division in the middle point. You need to add [`eps`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) to make the *L´hospital's rule* work.
Using it properly it becomes

```
y = sin(x+eps)./(x+eps);
```

Comment: perfect. Btw, if it solved your problem you can accept the answer, as it put the question as solved (and you got a *trophy* :).

Comment: Also, the division by zero does not works. i tried in in the [symbolic](https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) mode and it does not work as well.(at least in my 2014b version)

Comment: @Guto what do you mean it does not work? 0/0 is an undetermined mathematical term, the answer is not a number (NaN).

Comment: @AnderBiguri Numerically true, but by the L'Hospital theorem, this is =1.

Comment: @PhilipCina, I just added a bit about the sin(0)/0.

Comment: @Guto but you are using a numerical tool. MATLAB is not going to do L'Hopital for you!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Fortunately not :D . After i saw the problem i decided to make a comment on it as well. However i was initially expecting the Symbolic math to work, but it just work when using `limit`. Than the `eps` solve this problem faster.